# Getting weather info feeds from accuweather

Tags: android

I am developing an application to show the weather. I want to get data feed from [accuweather.com](http://www.accuweather.com/). I also bought a premium version at accuweather. I tried for more than 5 hours and I couldn't find the `RSS` url to get the feeds.

Comment: http://www.accuweather.com/en/downloads - scroll down and check "RSS Feed" tab, it may help,

Answer (score 3):

http://rss.accuweather.com/rss/liveweather_rss.asp?metric=1&locCode=55116

1. Metric 1 gives celsius results
2. Metric 2 gives fahrenheit results
3. Change zip code to your preference
4. Keep this info secret; keep it safe. They don't want anyone to know this,  it seems.

Answer (score 1):

http://rss.accuweather.com/rss/liveweather_rss.asp?locCode=10017

http://www.rsssearchhub.com/preview/new-york-ny-accuweather-com-forecast-rss-KPAPDm/

above links may help,

rsssearchub.com site has collection of all RSS, it's like search engine for RSS

I think it may help

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. But in the above link also we cant find the accurate accuweather feeds for weather.